# Error in method providing navigation between pages

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I am working on an app that I had originally written all in C# (including UI) but now I am rewriting it so that UI is handled by xml. Every part of the app worked fine when it was all in C#, however, now that I have switched UI over to xml, I am getting an error in my ViewModels.

error: 'StartPageViewModel' does not contain a definition for 'Navigation' and no accessible extension method 'Navigation' accepting a first argument of type 'StartPageViewModel' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

XML

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
         mc:Ignorable="d"
         x:Class="SampleApp.Views.StartPage">
<ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout>
        <Grid VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <Button x:Name="OnePlayerGame" Text="One Player Game" 
                    Command="{Binding StartOnePlayerGameCommand}" 
                    Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" 
                    HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
            <Button x:Name="TwoPlayerGame" Text="Two Player Game" 
                    Command="{Binding StartTwoPlayerGameCommand}"
                    Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalOptions="Center" />
        </Grid>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

Code behind

```
namespace SampleApp.Views
{
[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
public partial class StartPage : ContentPage
{
    public StartPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = new StartPageViewModel();
    }
}
}
```

ViewModel code

```
namespace SampleApp.ViewModels
{
class StartPageViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
    {
        var changed = PropertyChanged;
        if (changed == null)
            return;

        changed.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    public Command StartOnePlayerGameCommand { get; set; }
    public Command StartTwoPlayerGameCommand { get; set; }

    public StartPageViewModel()
    {
        StartOnePlayerGameCommand = new Command(() => StartOnePlayerGame());
        StartTwoPlayerGameCommand = new Command(() => StartTwoPlayerGame());
    }

    private void StartOnePlayerGame()
    {
        //the error is here (Navigation has a red squigly under it)
        this.Navigation.PushAsync(new Views.OnePlayerPage());
    }

    private void StartTwoPlayerGame()
    {
        //the error is here (Navigation has a red squigly under it)
        this.Navigation.PushAsync(new Views.NameEntryPage());
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Navigation is a property of the Page, not the VM

Answer (score 0):

`Navigation` is a property of Page and you can pass the Navigation through the `ViewModel` Constructor, then use it in the `ViewModel`:

```
class StartPageViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    public INavigation myNavigation { get; set; }

    public StartPageViewModel(INavigation navigation)
    {
        myNavigation = navigation;

        StartOnePlayerGameCommand = new Command(() => StartOnePlayerGame());
        StartTwoPlayerGameCommand = new Command(() => StartTwoPlayerGame());
    }

    private void StartOnePlayerGame()
    {
        //the error is here (Navigation has a red squigly under it)
        myNavigation.PushAsync(new Views.OnePlayerPage());
    }

    private void StartTwoPlayerGame()
    {
        //the error is here (Navigation has a red squigly under it)
        myNavigation.PushAsync(new Views.NameEntryPage());
    }
}
```

Pass it from Page:

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.BindingContext = new StartPageViewModel(Navigation);
    }
}
```

Another way it that you can try to use `Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation`:

```
private async void StartOnePlayerGame()
{
    //the error is here (Navigation has a red squigly under it)

    await Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushAsync(new Views.OnePlayerPage());
}
```